# Getting element not visible

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I have tried with the below expaths

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/button[1]/img")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/button[1]")).click();
```

It's not working. Please suggest me.

This the page source

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-fab demo-switcher-fab ng-scope" ng-if="innoassist_AuthUserdata.roles[21].create_permission != 0" ui-sref="App.addequipment" data-toggle="tooltip" tooltip="Add Asset" tooltip-placement="left" href="#/App/addequipment">
<img src="../theme-assets/images/plus.png">
</button>
```

Comment: Your xpath's are terrible because of the relative nature. Please read on why to use an absolute xpath instead of a relative one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wait until target button becomes visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='firsttimeloading']")));
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@tooltip='Add Asset']")));
button.click();
```

Comment: Tried with your code and getting the below error message                                                  unknown error: Element <button ng-if="innoassist_AuthUserdata.roles[21].create_permission != 0" ui-sref="App.addequipment" data-toggle="tooltip" tooltip="Add Asset" tooltip-placement="left" class="btn btn-success btn-fab demo-switcher-fab ng-scope" href="#/App/addequipment">...</button> is not clickable at point (1305, 102). Other element would receive the click: <div class="firsttimeloading firsttimeload" id="firsttimeloading" style="display: block;">...</div>

Comment: Is there any reason for deaccept the answer? Do you still need improvement of suggested solution?

Comment: Getting unknown error with the xpath
 can u solve tge above question also